# How to create a Kendo UI jQuery kendoDropDownList still allow user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I have a drop down list

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{unitName}" style="width: 100%;">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataUnitName = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/active_units_json",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            pageSize: 30
        });

        $("#unitId").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "unitName",
            dataValueField: "unitName",
            dataSource: dataUnitName,
            filter: "contains",
            index: 0,
            change: onChangeDataUnitName
        });
    });
    function onChangeDataUnitName() {

    }
</script>
```

Sometime I choose one from pre-defined list (at Kendo drop-down list). Sometime I want enter not belong to pre-defined list? How to do it?

Comment: If you want to enter into the input and select then you might want to look at [multiselect](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index)

Comment: `kendo.ui.MultiSelect` allow pick many items, I need one item. And it is from user input.

Comment: You could [restrict after first selection](http://dojo.telerik.com/EBIWE) but I don't think this is what you're looking for

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: take a look on [combobox](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index) widget

Comment: @VladaxLe it is exactly what I want. Please post your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on [combobox](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index) widget